# Remove SS2 and PU2 are coming as a extra characters in Java

Tags: java, special-characters

SS2 and PU2 are coming as a extra characters in a file which am reading but I could not read in console.How to remove such characters in Java.

[image]

Comment: while reading just check if string.contains("SS2" || "PU2"){
string.replace ("SS2", "")

Comment: @Dev I tried but Java could not remove  and could not find.Thanks for reply.

Comment: show some code..

Answer (score 1):

for SS2 : https://www.compart.com/fr/unicode/U+008E

```
byte[] bytes = {-62, -114};
SS2 = new String(bytes);
myString.replace(SS2, "")
```

or

```
SS2 = String.valueOf((char)Integer.parseInt("008E", 16));
myString.replace(SS2, "")
```

And for PU2 : https://www.compart.com/fr/unicode/U+0092

```
PU2 = String.valueOf((char)Integer.parseInt("0092", 16));
myString.replace(PU2, "")
```